# Changing state is causing multiple instances of babel/polyfill?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm using Meteor, Angular and Ionic. I'm having a hard time changing from state A to state B as I keep getting the error 'only one instance of babel/polyfill is allowed'. I tried cleaning up the following code as much as possible. Note that I can change to other states successfully.

Here's my routes.js file:

```
.state('create-group', {
    url:'/create-group:/:buddyId',
    templateUrl: 'client/templates/create-group.ng.html',
    controller: 'createGroupCtrl'
})
```

Here's my State A template:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="buddy in buddies" ng-click="createGroup({{buddy}})">
</ion-item>
```

Here's my State A controller:

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('whosDownCtrl', whosDownCtrl);

function whosDownCtrl ($scope, $state, $ionicScrollDelegate, $timeout, $meteor) {
    $scope.createGroup = createGroup;

    function createGroup(buddy) {
        $state.go('create-group', { buddyId: buddy._id});
    }
};
```

Here's my State B controller:

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('createGroupCtrl', createGroupCtrl);

function createGroupCtrl ($scope, $stateParams) {
    var clickedUser = $stateParams.buddyId;
}
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you manually add a babel/ecmascript package to meteor?

Check your .meteor/packages file and your .meteor/versions file because that error means there are multiple conflicting versions of babel added to your project.

And since all babel related meteor packages are independent wrappers, it is very likely to get such conflict.

Remove the "excess" babel packages and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old question but I landed here while analysing my issue. Posting here my learning as it may help others.

I was also getting the same error in my project. It was happening because there were issues with correct template and controller resolution. 
Here is a related github issue that helped in clarifying: https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/870

Use hardcoded template instead of templateUrl to analyse the issue properly.